# Number of non-isomorphic models

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

I had this question up on Math stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349247/number-of-non-isomorphic-models/1350763#1350763 . While it was answered partially there, I'm posting here in the hope that I might get a more detailed answer.

Let $C$ be the class of cardinals. Define by recursion $C_0 = C$, $C_\alpha = C_\beta\cup P(C_\beta)$ if $\alpha=\beta+1$ and $C_\alpha = \bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}{C_\beta}$ for limit $\alpha$ (Here $P(C_\beta)$ is the class of subsets of $C_\beta$).

We say that a complete theory $T$ has an invariant system of rank $\alpha$ iff there is some (class) function $f$ associating to each model of $T$ an element of $C_\alpha$ such that given models $A, B$ of $T$; $f(A)=f(B)$ iff A is isomorphic to B. And a theory $T$ is classifiable iff it has a invariant system of some rank $\alpha$.

I recently read that having $2^\lambda$ models for each uncountable cardinal $\lambda$ meant that you could not have an invariant system of the above style. I would like to know the reason why.

I know that classification theory is very complicated and technical, I would be quite happy with an intuitive answer that doesn't have all the details for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the global choice principle (which asserts that there is a class well-ordering of the set-theoretic universe), then every theory $T$ has rank $0$ as you define it, regardless of the number of models of the various uncountable sizes. The reason is that the well-ordering allows us to select a unique representative from each isomorphism class, and these representatives are themselves well-ordered in type at most Ord, which is bijective with $C_0$ via $\alpha\mapsto\aleph_\alpha$. So we can map the isomorphism classes injectively into $C_0$.

Comment: Perhaps the OP had meant to impose another requirement on $f$ that connected the size of the model $A$ to the value of $f(A)$?

Comment: I found this here: https://books.google.com/books?id=H0YYhu3DHh0C&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=%22invariant+system+of+rank%22&source=bl&ots=AuAg09eNhp&sig=AQAbRUZyiqt6X2YKUPV2U9c9fFU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vHKZVavsJ8moyATPsoOgCw&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22invariant%20system%20of%20rank%22&f=false

Comment: It does not mention such a restriction.

Comment: Indeed, it does not appear to mention a restriction on $f$ in the definition. It seems to me that theorem 7.1.6 claimed in the book is not correct, in light of my argument above.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like you have some sort of fix in mind. Would it be possible to add that as an edit to your answer?

Comment: I don't have any particular fix in mind; rather, I was merely speculating that Shelah had omitted condition on $f$ that would insist that $f(A)$ is chosen from the part of $C_\alpha$ using only cardinals up to and including $|A|$, or something like that. It seems plausible to me in that case that you couldn't find such a function for a fixed $\alpha$, since there might not be enough room.

Comment: When I said in my math.stackexchange answer that "it doesn't seem obviously inconsistent to me that there could be a theory $T$ with the maximal number of models ($2^\lambda$) in all uncountable $\lambda$ with an invariant system of rank $0$," I actually had this global choice argument in mind, but I hadn't really stopped to think about it. I'm glad you've confirmed that it works! Note that this definition is *not* due to Shelah, it's an interpretation of his work in the book by Marcja and Toffalori.

Comment: The cardinals which appear in the dimension invariants in Classification Theory are necessarily bounded above by the cardinality of $A$, just as you suggest.